# how to change button background from url?

Tags: ios, iphone

i have a url contains group of images , and from this url ,i want to change a button background as follows , but it fails and shows nothing , seems that some code is missing

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/Images/profiles/%@",ImgId]];

UIImage *imga = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];



UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:2013];
[btn setBackgroundImage:imga forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

however , the imga has a value of something like this "0x43530293".
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that, tableView contains of **[self.tableView viewWithTag:2013]**

Comment: Your way of referencing the button looks a bit suspicious. Do you want to elaborate that? Why did you add it as a subview?

Comment: What is the type of button make sure that it is of type Custom

Comment: do you mean that the image is downloaded correctly! and the problem in the button referencing! , but it i try to change it locally and it works with this reference to the button!

Answer (score 1):

I have take the static image url and put button on view with tag 2013 this code works fine.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg"]];

UIImage *imga = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];



UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2013];
[btn setBackgroundImage:imga forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: i have done this and its working fine. simple you put button on view tag the button 2013 and put my code with your url.

Comment: I have updated code now. you simply put the code and button with tag 2013